# QtWebEngine and WebInspector

Tags: qt, debugging, web-inspector, qtwebengine

I'm trying to use chrom web inspector to debug web pages, that shows up in web views of my applicaion. This application works well in MacOS, but on win 10 and win 7 web inspector works only if application started from QtCreator (no meter, if it is debug or release mode). Chrome still connecting to local port of application and shows the link to web page, but the page is empty. All other functions of application - works well.
Instruments: Qt5.8 with msvs2015, QtWebEngine and Google Chrome.
Don't know, if this information would helps, but i'm using windeployqt for putting together dll's for target file.
For binding port I use this code:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
qputenv("QTWEBENGINE_REMOTE_DEBUGGING","9090");
QtWebEngine::initialize();
```

So, does anyone know, how can I use web inspector without starting my application from QtCreator?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is to to make a .bat file. Inside it just call you application exe with and argument

```
yourapplication.exe --remote-debugging-port=9090
```

Answer (score 0):

I see only one solution. After copying libs with the help of windeployqt, replace Qt5Core.dll in the app folder from 5.8\msvc2015\bin. This lib has one little difference that somehow connecting it to another libs in bin directory (I guess). 
In that case it is better to start programm with argument "--remote-debugging-port=9090". So it works, but only on computer there Qt has been installed.
Bad solution, but I didn't find out another.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I am getting following error while enabling remote debug the qt web engine page using chrome browser with the environment as mentioned in the previous comments.
[image]